# how to set a kube network policy on a specific host?

Tags: networking, kubernetes

How do I define a network policy YML file so it only allows traffic to and from a hostname like console.cloud.ibm.com?

I only can find how to block from certain IP addresses or namespaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Network Policies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/) to block the IP address of what resolves to:

```
$ dig +short console.cloud.ibm.com
23.204.34.209
```

The downside is that the IP might change. Network policies are a layer 3 or IP layer feature so you won't see hostnames there. Some background [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/50453)

If you want to block on hostname you might consider using a Service Mesh like [Istio](https://istio.io/) with [Envoy](https://www.envoyproxy.io/) which will allow you to control traffic to a `host` by using [Egress Control](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/).